# HOTP - correct use of RFC sample

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to realize a sample which uses the [RFC4226 - HOTP: An HMAC-Based One-Time Password Algorithm](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt) as base.

I took the code sample and added:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    // Seed
    String secret = "12345678901234567890";
    byte[] secretBytes = secret.getBytes();

    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 9; counter++) {
        String strGeneratedToken = OneTimePasswordAlgorithm.generateOTP(secretBytes, counter, 6, false, 0);
        System.out.println(strGeneratedToken);
    }
}
```

All I'm getting is:

**755224**
717529
868666
023335
179456
490877
910469
467724
952310

The first one is OK, but the next one (counter=1) as per RFC (**755224** 287082 359152 969429 338314 254676 287922 162583 399871 520489).

I've uploaded my code to GitHub https://github.com/n0l0cale/hotp - maybe someone is able to see the issue.

This implementation seems to have the same issue:
http://read.pudn.com/downloads158/sourcecode/others/706340/MessageAuthenticationExample.java__.htm

I would nevermind, but when I try the same secret for My Java Application and My [Google Authenticator App](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android/tree/master/AuthenticatorApp/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/authenticator) I'm also getting other codes. "12345678901234567890" of course does not work as secret, but I've tried with the same passphrase and Google Authenticator App seems to start their counter by 0, but increments their counter with it's first usage...

Answer (score 1):

truncationOffset seems to be required to be set to 16.....

String strGeneratedToken = OneTimePasswordAlgorithm.generateOTP(secretBytes, counter, 6, false, **16**);

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    // Seed
    String secret = "12345678901234567890";
    byte[] secretBytes = secret.getBytes();

    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 9; counter++) {
        String strGeneratedToken = OneTimePasswordAlgorithm.generateOTP(secretBytes, counter, 6, false, 16);
        System.out.println(strGeneratedToken);
    }
}
```

755224
287082
359152
969429
338314
254676
287922
162583
399871
520489